# Previous commandlet in the Pipeline

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a powershell pipeline function and wondering if there is a way to find out which was the previous command in the pipeline.

```
Get-ChildItem | format-nice
```

Is there a way to find in the context of format-nice that Get-ChildItem was is the previous commandlet on the pipeline?

Thanks,
Shiju

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Get-PSCallStack to locate the pipeline commands within the function to locate the previous command that was used. So a function like this...

```
Function Pipeline {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        $InputObject
    )
    $PreviousCommand = (Get-PSCallStack).InvocationInfo[1].MyCommand.Definition
    Write-Verbose "Command: $(($PreviousCommand | Out-String))"
}
```

...could then be used in a pipeline and you can tell what commands were used in the pipeline.

```
Get-ChildItem | Pipeline -Verbose
```

*VERBOSE: Command: Get-ChildItem | Pipeline -Verbose*

```
Get-ChildItem | 
Get-Item | 
Pipeline -Verbose
```

*VERBOSE: Command: Get-ChildItem | 
Get-Item | 
Pipeline -Verbose*

Bear in mind that this is fragile and if you run multiple commands in a single execution beyond what is going via the pipeline that it will display more stuff. For instance if you call the function and run the commands in the same execution, it could end up like this:

*VERBOSE: Command: Function Pipeline {
[cmdletbinding()]
Param(
[parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
$InputObject
)
$PreviousCommand = (Get-PSCallStack).InvocationInfo[1].MyCommand.Definition
Write-Verbose "Command: $(($PreviousCommand | Out-String))"
} 
Get-ChildItem | Pipeline -Verbose*